# Active Directory User Search in Spring

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, active-directory, spring-security-ldap

I have implemented Active Directory Authentication using Spring Security and it's working fine. Now i want to get details of other users using their `sAMAccountName`. This Functionality I need for Admin to approve or reject user in our application. Using below code I'm able to fetch logged in user details.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
```

How to use this `Authentication` object to fetch other user details.
I'm using `spring-security-ldap-4.0.1` `spring-security-core-4.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [`UserDetailsContextMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/UserDetailsContextMapper.html). There are already implementing classes that automatically map some attributes of a LDAP objects like `InetOrgPersonContextMapper` or `PersonContextMapper`. If there is any special attribute you'll have to enroll your own, e.g. we have reporting lines stored in AD using attributes of `manager` and `directReports` which I had to map manually.

```
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    @Autowired
    private LdapUserService ldapUserService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ops, String username,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ops, username, authorities);

        String manager = ops.getStringAttribute("manager");
        String[] directReports = ops.getStringAttributes("directReports");

        User user = new User(
                username, 
                "", 
                details.isEnabled(), 
                details.isAccountNonExpired(), 
                details.isCredentialsNonExpired(), 
                details.isAccountNonLocked(), 
                details.getAuthorities(), 
                manager,
                directReports); 

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter dir) {
        super.mapUserToContext(user, dir);
    }

}
```

And obviously you'll also have to tweak your `UserDetails` as well:

```
public class User extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    private String manager;
    private String[] directReports;

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String manager, String[] directReports) {
        this(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.manager = manager;
        this.directReports = directReports;
    }

    public String getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public String[] getDirectReports() {
        return directReports;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.